# Can DataNucleus persist an abstract base class parameterized with Generics?

Tags: java, generics, jdo, datanucleus, type-erasure

Using DataNucleus, I have been happy using an abstract base class to provide a 'long' ID to the sub-classes (please note the primitive type).

When adapting an [example from JPA](http://aurelavramescu.blogspot.com/2011/04/jpa-with-google-guice.html) I got the idea to parameterize the base class. The purpose was to support different ID types, such as String.

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
@Version(strategy=VersionStrategy.VERSION_NUMBER, column="jdo_version")
public abstract class VersionedIdEntity<P>
    implements Serializable {

  static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
  private P id;

  public P getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

Generics made me use the wrapped Java type 'Long', so sub-classes were declared like this:

```
public class Account extends VersionedIdEntity<Long>
```

My switch to the new base class caused an error stating that no implementation for 'java.lang.Object' was found.

> org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Field "VersionedIdEntity.id" is declared as a reference type (interface/Object) but no implementation classes of "java.lang.Object" have been found!

Is the error related to type erasure?

Additional questions would be (1) how JPA deals with it and (2) whether I can restrict the type P to [types persistable in DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/types.html), such as:

```
<? extends PersistableType>
```

While I could not find help elsewhere, the question could have been asked before. In that event, a brief pointer would be much appreciated.

Comment: The JPA example you have listed is not the same as what you are attempting to do. Notice that the abstract class AbstractEntity does not **declare** the ID field. This is left to the implementing subclasses.

Comment: @JamesB: Thank you. Your answer was the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean does JDO define that an implementation should support this? Answer : no. 
JDO defines the valid PK types, and what is a "P" ? it is Object as far as a class is concerned (i.e (java.lang.)Object, since it doesn't have the real type there). Neither does JPA define it for that matter.

Comment: I am just a newbie trying to learn about persistence. I'll take your response as a yes to my question about type erasure. Thank you. If you are involved with the @DataNucleus project, thank you also for that great persistence platform and your availability to answer questions about it. It's an intimidating dialog (reputation of 6 vs. reputation of 7,130).