# Java - Generic variable becomes java.lang.Object when looking through reflection

Tags: java, google-app-engine, generics, google-cloud-datastore

I have a generic class as follows:

```
public MyClass<T>{
 T id;
 public T getId(){return id;}
 public void setId(T id){this.id=id;}
}
```

I instantiate it as follows:

```
MyClass<String> myClass = new MyClass<String>();
```

When looking the getId() method through reflection (i == the index of the getId method):

```
myClass.getClass().getMethods()[i].getReturnType();
```

It will say that the return type is java.lang.Object.

I'm guessing I'm asking the impossible here, but, would it somehow be possible for the class to actually say java.lang.String in this case?

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm using App engine and it's Datastore. A simplified scenario: I got all my classes inheriting from MyClass and therefore they get a id with the type T, where T is either Long, String or Key. But the datastore thinks no matter what that the id field is an java.lang.Object, which is prohibited. Do I need to make classes like MyClassString, MyClassLong etc, or is there some way i can bypass this?

Thank you!

EDIT: After searching for another issue I had after "solving" this. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658992/can-datanucleus-persist-an-abstract-base-class-parameterized-with-generics) actually mentioning my exact problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type arguments for the parameterized type are lost at runtime through a process known as type erasure.  At runtime there is no way to determine the method returns a `String`, since the actual type arguments used are not available.

[Generic Faq](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20erasure?)

One way to work around this would be implement a generic interface, which would allow the objects to be used in a polymorphic manner:

**Identifiable.java**

```
public interface Identifiable<T> {
    T getId();
    void setId(T t);
}
```

**Person.java**

```
public class Person implements Identifiable<String> {

    private String id;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(String t) {
        this.id = t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        Method method = person.getClass().getMethods()[1]; //prints getId
        System.out.println(method.getName());
        System.out.println(method.getGenericReturnType());  //prints String
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In other words: I have to create a MyClassString, MyClassLong etc?

Comment: I would just create the fields as normal with getters and setters.  If you want to obtain the ID in a polymorpohic manner maybe try an interface instead.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing almost like this, instead of an interface its an abstract class with some extra functionality!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by storing a class variable within and returning this on request.

i.e.

```
public MyClass<T>{
 Class<T> clazz;
 T id;
 public T getId(){return id;}
 public void setId(T id){this.id=id;}

 MyClass(Class<T> clazz) {
   this.clazz=clazz
 }

 public Class<T> getIdClass() { return clazz; }
}
```

Now to find out what type your class is you can just call getIdClass() on it and use that returned type. Generics will enforce that the type is set correctly when an instance of MyClass is created.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification can be added to Tim B's solution, if you do not want parametrized constructor.

```
public class MyClass<T>{
     Class<T> clazz;
     T id;
     public T getId(){return id;}
     public void setId(T id){this.id=id;}

     public Class<?> getIdClass() { 
         if (id != null) {
             return id.getClass();  
         } else {
             return Object.class;
         }
     }
}
```

You can check it by

```
MyClass<String> myClass = new MyClass<String>();
        myClass.setId("abc");
        System.out.println(myClass.getIdClass());
```

Comment: Well this (and Tim B's) solution doesn't answer my whole question unfortunately. I wanted the whole field to be interpreted as the real Type and not as java.lang.Object, but this is impossible due to type erasure as Kevin pointed out. Thank you for your efforts though!